# How to copy a csv file into a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, cs50

I'm working on cs50's pset6, DNA, and I want to read a csv file that looks like this:

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
Bob,4,1,5
Charlie,3,2,5
```

But the problem is that dictionaries only have a key, and a value, so I don't know how I could structure this. What I currently have is this piece of code:

```
import sys

with open(argv[1]) as data_file:
    data_reader = csv.DictReader(data_file)
```

And also, my csv file has multiple columns and rows, with a header and the first column indicating the name of the person. I don't know how to do this, and I will later need to access the individual amount of say, `Alice`'s value of `AATG`.

Also, I'm using the module `sys`, to import `DictReader` and also `reader`

Comment: Did you try and do *anything* with `data_reader`?

Comment: For each row in the csv file there will be one entry in the dictionary. The key will be the name from the first column of the row. The value will be a tuple created from the remaining columns for that row. Is that what you are aiming for?

Comment: Dictionary values can be containers like tuples, lists, sub-dictionaries, etc — so do as @Wilf suggests and make `row[0]` the key and put `row[1]` to `row[3]` into on of them and make that the associated value.

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't know what is that...

Comment: You want something like this [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/AquamarineShamefulSpellchecker#main.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try to create the function on your own.

You can use my code here:

```
def csv_to_dict(csv_file):
    key_list = [key for key in csv_file[:csv_file.index('\n')].split(',')] # save the keys
    data = {} # every dictionary
    info = [] # list of dicitionaries
    # for each line
    for line in csv_file[csv_file.index('\n') + 1:].split('\n'):
        count = 0 # this variable saves the key index in my key_list.
        # for each string before comma
        for value in line.split(','):
            data[key_list[count]] = value # for each key in key_list (which I've created before), I put the value. This is the way to set a dictionary values.
            count += 1
        info.append(data) # after updating my data (dictionary), I append it to my list.
        data = {} # I set the data dictionary to empty dictionary.
    print(info) # I print it.

### Be aware that this function prints a list of dictionaries.
```

Comment: could you explain what you did.

Comment: I have edited comments that might help understand.
Basically, I have translated this CSV file data (which given as string) to a list of dictionaries.

The first line gives me the keys and the others their values -
I took each line and saved it as a dictionary and then appended it to list.

Hope this and the edition help you understand!